# PHP MYSQL like button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

Hi i have made a like button for a commenting feed that i have but every time i click it it reloads the page i would like to make it so that it dose not reload the page. i cant find the answer to my question anywhere. i understand that i would have to use javascript or AJAX but as i do not know how to code in that i am stuck.

This is on the page where my commenting feeds are. the name of the page is member-index.php

```
<a href=\"like-exec.php?id=".$rows['ID']."&members_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."\">like</a>
```

and this is on the page that executes the code (like-exec.php)

```
<?php
require('../config/connect.php');
require('../config/config.php');

$sql = "UPDATE comments set `like` = `like`+1 where `ID` = '$_GET[id]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("likes", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (members_id, comm_id) VALUES(".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].", $id)");


mysql_close($con);
header("location: success.php");

?>
```

after that code has finished it gets sent to susses.php that then redirects it to member-index.php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**PHP/HTML**

Add a class to your 'like' links so that we can target it easier in jQuery and make the id of the link the row id. It's also worth checking you don't have numerical id's elsewhere on the page since these are going to be simple id's that are easily used elsewhere in your markup.

```
<a class="like" id="<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?>" href=\"like-exec.php?id=".$rows['ID']."&members_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."\">like</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a.like').click(function() {
    // triggered when like link is clicked

    // get the id of this link
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // make the AJAX request to the PHP script that updates the database table

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: update_likes.php,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: ({ id: id }), // first id is the name, second is the actual id variable we just created
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            // you can do stuff in here before you send the data, display spinner gif etc
            alert('sending!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // same here but when the ajax request is successful
            // the data variable is coming from the echo of your PHP script
            alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            // yet again but on completion
            alert('complete!');
        }

    });

    // stops the browser following the link (href) in the a tag
    return false;

});
```

**PHP**

A new script that we send the ajax request to but it's just the same code you already have in your question.

**update_likes.php**

```
<?php
require('../config/connect.php');
require('../config/config.php');

// not sure if session_start(); is in your config but you will need it
// in this script somewhere to do your second query.

// $_GET['id'] is now coming via ajax

$sql = "UPDATE comments set `like` = `like`+1 where `ID` = '$_GET[id]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("likes", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (members_id, comm_id) VALUES(".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].", $id)");


mysql_close($con);

// header("location: success.php");
// don't need this anymore

// only echo one string from an ajax request so if you need more do some
// concatenation
echo 'successfully updated db!';

?>
```

On a final note, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated so look into PDO or msqli.

P.S. I haven't tested the code but **hopefully** it should just work.

**UPDATE**

Try changing the click function to this:

```
$('a.like').click(function(e) {
    // triggered when like link is clicked


    // stops the browser following the link (href) in the a tag
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the id of this link
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // make the AJAX request to the PHP script that updates the database table

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: update_likes.php,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: ({ id: id }), // first id is the name, second is the actual id variable we just created
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            // you can do stuff in here before you send the data, display spinner gif etc
            alert('sending!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // same here but when the ajax request is successful
            // the data variable is coming from the echo of your PHP script
            alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            // yet again but on completion
            alert('complete!');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: thats but one last thing everything works except the return false; part it still follows the link. any idea why?

Comment: hmm, it shouldn't be happening but just to be sure, try taking out the href of your links and just use `#` as the href attribute, if the browser still follows the link then at worst it will scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: i have tried. could it be the fact that i am using MAMP? i will be uploading it to a web sever soon im hoping it will work then.

Comment: jQuery should work locally as it's client side, not server side. Is your jQuery inside a document ready function? http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: i have tried that and it still dose not work. i have other javascript scripts on the same page and they work fine its just this one. PS. thank you so much for all your help i really appreciate it.

Comment: @TristanMichaelSmith - I've updated the jquery, try that and see if it works now.

Comment: I have implemented this to shiny app, but when I click link:

`<a class="like" id="<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?>" href=\"like-exec.php?id=".$rows['ID']."&members_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."\">like</a>` 
browser is trying to download `like-exec.php` not run. Can you help?

Comment: Hi @Taz, probably best creating a new question for that but sounds like an error to do with the url or the permissions of the php file maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="like" href=\"like-exec.php\" comment-id=".$rows['ID']." members-id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."\">like</a>
```

Try to use JQuery to call PHP in AJAX.

```
$(".like").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      type: "GET",
      data: { comment-id: $(this).attr("comment-id"), members-id: $(this).attr("members-id")},
      success:function(result){

         if(result.success) {
            // Success
         }else{
            // Not success
         }

      },
      error: function(request,status,error){
         // Request error
      }
    });    

});
```

In PHP you can get the variables with `$_GET["comment-id"]` and `$_GET["members-id"]`.
When your script has success you can define information in an array and you can encode it in JSON. Afterwards, you have to use `echo` to generate the response:

```
echo json_encode(array(
   "success" => true
));
```

If your script has no success, you can define this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => false,
    "reason" => "some reason"
));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `jquery` added to your website, you can make an ajax calls like this.

Firstly, we update the like link so that it calls javascript rather that directly links to the webserver.  So, update your link to :

```
<a href=\"like-exec.php?id=".$rows['ID']."&members_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."\" onclick="updateLike($(this));return false;">like</a>
```

Then we add the javascript to handle the ajax update component.  I have put the responses from the server as simple alerts, but you could try updating the html directly or placing some inline updates.  The following javascript needs to be added into the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateLike(elm)
{
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url: elm.attr('href'),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      // TODO : User friendly error message on ajax fail
      alert("Request Error :" + xhr + status + err);
  }

  success: function(resp) {
      // ajax operation was successful - confirm the like was okay
      if (resp.success) {
         window.location(resp.redirect);
      } else {
         // TODO : User friendly error message on update fail
         alert("Like failed : " + resp.error);
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

`$.ajax()` function performs the ajax operation. The `error` property handles issues where the client failed to communicate with the server or did not get a valid response. The `success` property handles instances where the server responded.  `success` will further need to check if the update was successful or not.

The following is the server side code for the likes update.  You have used `mysql_*` functions, so I have kept these intact.  However, bear in mind that these functions are now deprecated in favour of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). You should consider updating the code to reflect this.

```
<?php
require('../config/connect.php');
require('../config/config.php');

$error = "";

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con)
{
   $error = "Unable to connect to database.";
} else {

   // Check the database is available
   $db = mysql_select_db("likes", $con);

   if (!$db)
   {
      $error = "Unable to select like database.";
   } else {
      // Moved update to after connecting with database
      $sql = "UPDATE comments set `like` = `like`+1 where `ID` = '" . $_GET[id] . "'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      if (!$result) { // Check query is successful
         $error .= "Error when updating comment likes.";
      }

      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (members_id, comm_id)
      VALUES(".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].", $id)");
      if (!$result) { // Check insert is successful
         $error .= "Error when inserting member likes.";
      }
   }

   mysql_close($con);
}

// Convert output to a JSON object for jquery to handle
$resp = new Object();
if ($error == "")
{
   $resp->success = true;
   $resp->redirect = "success.php";
} else {
   $resp->error = $error;
   $resp->success = false;
}

echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

The code above is untested; so there may be typos/bugs/errors but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you sooo much i have been trying to figure this out for months!

Comment: just one last thing it seams so be coming up with an error for the: success: function(resp) i dont know why though?